# Why can't I see my php code rendered on page?

Tags: php, html, include, render

Just getting started with php.  In index.php I have

```
<?php
 echo 'test';
?>
```

and when I go to localhost:8080/php/index.php  I see 'test'.  However I made an HTML file index.html with this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'index.php'; ?>
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

but all I see is 'Welcome to my home page' and no 'test'.   Wondering what I'm missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: haha i know its a noob question but why is this voted down so i can avoid such habits in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the file extension from `.html` to `.php`

Change `index.html` to `index.php`

**NOTE**: You can't execute php code in `.html` files.

Also one more thing, you need to change both file names. because you are changing index.html to index.php and another file with same name is already there.

so do this.

**index_inc.php**

```
<?php
 echo 'test';
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'index_inc.php'; ?>
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or parse the particular html file or all html files as php

Comment: *"NOTE: You can't execute php code in .html files."* - Not entirely true. You can tell Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. I'll let you Google that.

Answer (score 1):

Your file's extension is `.html` , so php code will not be excuted.
if you really want to let the .html file to excute php code, you can write a `.htaccess` file
and add the line

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

Comment: you can, with a commons setting change.

Comment: *"You can not use php code in a html file."* - Not true. I'll let you Google "treat html as php" then come back and edit your answer to reflect your findings.

Comment: Thank you. I get new knowledge.